# At which speed (tempo) is an international piano concertist able to play an arpeggio, like F sharp (black keys only)

Tags: piano, arpeggios

I'm struggling to play fast the F sharp arpeggio (this is black key only : F#-A#-C#-F#-A#-C#-etc)

Currently, I play this arpeggio on 4 octaves at the tempo of 130 for 4 notes (with no mistakes) after one month of huge work. I'm an amateur though.

I believe that one should be able to play at least at 160 in order to have the respect the tempo of arpeggios as defined in Chopin etude opus 25 number 12.

This looks impossible to me to get 30 more on the metronome in order to move from 130 to 160.
For example, I see that Valentina Lisitsa (world class piano concertist) is playing much slower than what is written in this study... I computed that she plays it at a tempo of 148, which is already 8% below the tempo.

So the question is : *at which speed (tempo) is an international piano concertist able to play an arpeggio, like F sharp (difficult because all notes are black keys)*.

(Or should I understand that tempo written on scores is actually impossible, even for world class international pianist ? If so, why do composers write something that is impossible for an human, thus impossible for the composer ?)

Comment: What you -- or I -- can do has very little to do with what accomplished professionals can do.  There's a reason that most of us have zero chance of making a living from playing our instrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair, Chopin's op.25 no.12 does not require you to play (on either one hand) the root, third, AND fifth of a chord, so one could argue that it is easier to play faster compared to arpeggios with all three tones of a chord because you would not have to perform a thumb-under manoeuver (I am, of course, assuming that by F# arpeggio, you mean F#-A#-C#-F#-A#-C#-...).

More on arpeggios -- some versions of Chopin's op.10 no.1 has the tempo marked as *Allegro* (MM176).  Like the aforementioned etude, the thumb-under is not required to play these arpeggios, but most of these arpeggios span a tenth as opposed to just an octave.

Now to answer your question:

> at which speed (tempo) is an international piano concertist able to play an arpeggio, like F sharp (difficult because all notes are black keys).

You can expect a concert pianist to be able to play the music **to the written (or implied) tempo, which will then further differ due to style and interpretation**.  Unfortunately, there is not -- and in my opinion, should not -- be a concrete answer to this question.  I suppose, however, that the absolute minimum tempo could be 92 as required by the RCM Associate Diploma for Piano Pedagogy; technical tests are not required for the diploma for piano performance, but surely you would expect world class performers to be able to reach *well* beyond this number.

Hope this answers your question.  Please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: thank you very much : could you comment about the 92 : 92 for how many notes ?

Comment: 92 quarters, arpeggios played as sixteenths, so four notes.

Comment: thank you. ok, so 92 seems to able to anybody that plays piano.